# What Kashrut Agency Uses this Symbol?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, symbols-symbology, organizations

I found this symbol on a box of chocolates today:

[image: BKN (backwards B, small N attached to the K)]

It was on a box of chocolates from this company - http://www.hauserchocolates.com.

Anybody recognize the agency?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Kashrut.com](http://www.kashrut.com/agencies/#NY) lists that symbol as belonging to Rabbi Mordechai Kaplinsky, in Brooklyn, NY. See there for contact information.

Comment: Did you image-search that image or find it by scanning occuly?

Comment: @WAF I used the faculties the Good Lord, Blessed Be He, gave me.

Comment: The Good Lord has apparently granted you more faculties than He did Google | [Inside Search](http://goo.gl/YtXtQ2). . .