# Who or what is OV? (kosher symbol)

Tags: kashrut-kosher, symbols-symbology, organizations

In the store earlier, I saw a kosher symbol I had never seen before, and was wondering if anyone here knows what organization it represents.

Here is the symbol:

[image: picture of a kosher symbol on a package, with a "V" inside an "O," similar to the OU kosher symbol]

Comment: In defense of the on-topicness of this question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34000/5323

Comment: What about the O-R just above it?

Comment: @DoubleAA the [registered trademark symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_trademark_symbol)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's the symbol of the [Vaad Hoeir of St. Louis](http://www.ovkosher.org/).

Comment: @Shokhet, I had to be fast so I could beat [msh210](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=9247003#9247003) to the punch. :)

Comment: Ah, got it. `:)`

Comment: I thought the Vaad was careful that the V in the heksher would have the lines on the top?  I've seen a plain v in a circle used to designate vegetarian and it was my understanding that this was how they distinguished their symbol (but perhaps I'm incorrect).

Comment: @Yirmeyahu Are you talking about the [serifs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serif)?

Comment: @Bachrach44, yes, that was the word I was looking for.

Comment: @Shokhet Hi Shok. Be aware that the vaad's web site warns that their OV symbol is also being used by companies certifying products that are vegetarian but not necessarily kosher: http://cor.ca/view/218/confusion_regarding_the_ov_symbol.html